# Adding icon to label in google chart

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to display a png-icon, off lets say 16x16 pixels, as a label instead of the standard text?

I want to make an bar chart with on the base of the bars, a little icon which symbols the label. 
This is the data of the table:

```
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Type', 'Amount'],
          ['ecological',  4],
          ['social',  3],
          ['natural',  660]
        ]);
```

The `type`-label I want to represent by an icon.

If it's not possible with an bar chart, is it then possible with a Pie chart?